# searching and replacing content from one file to another file using a keyword using python or java

Tags: java, python

I have 2 files which contains some data like this!!

**File 1 contains:**

```
/begin MENT AE0DAQ0O41 ""
  ECU_ADDRESS 0x8111DSCC
  ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION 0x0
  /begin IF_DATA CAN_EXT
    120
    LINK_MAP "AE0DAQ0O41" 0x8111DSCC 0x0 0 0x2 1 0x2F 0x1
    DISPLAY 0 0 655
  /end IF_DATA
  SYMBOL_LINK "AE0DAQ0O41" 0
/end MENT
```

**File 2 contains:**

```
  name            value    line   keyword   
 .data           80008114+000005 AE0DAQ0O43
 .data           80008116+000005 AE0DAQ0O41
 .data           80008118+000005 EA0DAQ0O45
 .data           8000811a+000005 AE0DAF0O89
```

Now what we need to do is take a keyword `AE0DAQ0O41` and need to search in the next file.

It has some value before the keyword, so we need to take that value `80008116` and need to replace it in 
`ECU_ADDRESS 0x8111DSCC` and also `LINK_MAP AE0DAQ0O41` `0x8111DSCC 0x0 0 0x2 1 0x2F 0x1` for (`0x8111DSCC` it needs to be `0x80008116`) and save it to `FILE 1`.

**FILE 1 is to be saved like this :**

```
/begin MENT AE0DAQ0O41 ""
  ECU_ADDRESS 0x80008116
  ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION 0x0
  /begin IF_DATA CAN_EXT
    120
    LINK_MAP "AE0DAQ0O41" 0x80008116 0x0 0 0x2 1 0x2F 0x1
    DISPLAY 0 0 655
  /end IF_DATA
  SYMBOL_LINK "AE0DAQ0O41" 0
/end MENT
```

How do we do that ??? because it has multiple lines like this ????
Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: are they both .txt files.

Comment: considering it a text file you can read it put it in a dictionary and then go through that dictionary or list each time and write it back to the file. In python have no idea of doing it in java.

Comment: Use simple open , read , split and write function they are built-in it'll do your job. For further goto Python docs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code writing service + OP behaviour (see [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433744/convert-my-python-code-to-java-code))

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your `File 2` as a **tab seperated value** file then you could read the `File 1` line by line and then compare the keyword in the `file1` with each line in `file2`.

When you get a match then write another file with the new inputs

Comment: I have not written a code but i have done something similar like this. I dont have the code right now. But you can try implementing this logic. Be optimistic. 
Give your sample code here so that we can see what is not working!!

Comment: In StackOverflow dont expect people to code for you. We can only help you only if you encounter an error or face any challanges during implementing.

Dont assume that you will get anything readymade. You need to atleast read up a few doc and try implementation.

Comment: Ganesh i dont have any problem in giving you the code. I just want you also to learn!!! i will try to code it later and post it!!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:
(Assuming that the inputs are both text files...)

The code creates a dictionary by mining the second file.
The first file is processed line by line and written to the output file after the required modifications.

This is certainly not the best way to go about it. 
If you know the exact format of the files, you can optimize the code to run a lot faster.

```
fout = open('output.txt' , 'w')

beg, ecu, lnk = '/begin','ECU_ADDRESS', 'LINK_MAP'

keyVal = dict()
with open('file2.txt') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        b = line.split(' ')
        newK, newV = b[-1].replace('\n','') , b[-2].split('+')[0]
        keyVal[newK] = newV

with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    value,keyword = '', ''
    for line in f1:
        a = line.split(' ')
        loc = 0

        if beg in a and 'MENT' in a:
            keyword = a[a.index(beg)+2]
            value = '0x'+keyVal.get(keyword,keyword)
        elif ecu in a:
            loc = a.index(ecu) + 1
        elif lnk in a: loc = a.index(lnk) + 2
        else : loc = 0

        if loc != 0:
            a[loc] = value
        a = ' '.join(a)
        fout.writelines(a)

fout.close()
```

Comment: it seems to be working ..what exactly is the error? What are your file formats? You need to provide more details not just 'not working'

Comment: great! the code looks up the key in the dictionary compiled from the second file and then replaces the instances in the first file..since its working you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry,  I have explained the code's logic, the rest should be self evident...if not please consult python documentation

Comment: please verify that the data format is consistent across files. In case of any deviations, you can tweak the code or format the test data set

Comment: that should be a fairly straightforward tweak